# How to include two C++ libraries - Boost and Quantlib - in node gyp?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node-gyp, quantlib

I am new to working with node-gyp in making C++ Addons for JavaScript on Windows and have been struggling for a while with including Quantlib in my binding.gyp file. I was able to generate the .lib file from Quantlib's official site (https://www.quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml); however, the guide did not mention anything about generating a .dll file, and I am not sure if a .dll file is needed to include Quantlib. Although I cannot include the Quantlib library, I have been successful in linking another C++ library in my binding.gyp file. Any help would be much appreciated!

My binding.gyp file:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "hello",
      "sources": [ "src/hello.cc", "src/test.cpp", "src/test.h"],
      "include_dirs": ["<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")", "eigen-3.3.7/eigen-3.3.7", "ql/math", "ql", "Quantlib"],
      "libraries": ["<(module_root_dir)/Quantlib/QuantLib-mt.lib"]
    }
  ]
}
```

NOTE: eigen-3.3.7 is the C++ library I was able to include in my binding.gyp file. I created a directory in my root folder for quantlib's .lib file called "Quantlib".

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to switch from gyp to cmakejs. I made even a video about this with links to a boilerplate github repo: https://youtu.be/jpH5-DXDovk

Comment: The quantlib even has a cmakelists.txt, meaning, if you are using CMakeJS you could just add it as a git submodule load it into your cmake project and then let take care cmakejs for the C++/JS wrapper.

Comment: @Superlokkus thanks for suggesting this! I just watched your video and think I could try doing this. However, I just wanted to ask - how would I reference the cmakelists.txt from the quantlib submodule? Would I write something like add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Quantlib), target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Quantlib) and include(Quantlib/cmake/quantlib.cmake) in my project's cmakelists.txt? Moreover, if I wanted to create a C++ addon that depends on other helper functions from other files would I need to reference all targets in the cmakelists.txt too?

Comment: Yes something like that, however for good CMake packages target_link_libraries, headers will also be included otherwise use target_include_directories. But now we get to the point, cmake helps you deal with good and bad libraries. I dont know how good the quantlib cmake is written. Best case you build it once and refert it via find_package and CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH also setable via cmakejs. Otherwise git submodule ad add_subdirectory. But thats then the same hassle as with any native C++ library. But at least you get addtional gyp related problems.

Comment: @Superlokkus I just tried your example repo, spielwiese, and I run into this error when trying to configure and build the CMake. 

# cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..

CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package)

Comment: You need boost (often found under libboost in most packagemanagers) installed i.e. lying around.